# loop through Row PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I was able to retrieve data from Mysql database however every 4 column I need to close row  and start and new row 
Following is my HTML code that I am trying to loop through columns and after every 4 columns close the row and keep adding columns from database. 
[image]

Here is my code (I know this is not PDO and I am trying to learn so I can convert to PDO MySQLi connection)

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">

    <?php
       include('dbconnect.php');
       $query = "SELECT * FROM selection"; 
       mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    for($i=1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++){
    ?>
             <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> <strong><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                          <p>
                             <?php echo $row['ContactInfo']; ?><br/>
                             <img class="img-responsive" src="http://myurl.com/selections/<?php echo $row['file_url']; ?>" >
                          </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


             <?php
                }
             ?>
```

I need to add a new for loop but I haven't been successful so far. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be copied
into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, making other
users with the same problem less likely to find the answer
here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant
text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Comment: Sorry Toby. I will do a better job next time.

Comment: It is not fully related to the question, but I see you are using bootstrap, and you want to display 4 columns each row. 

So you don't actually need to create a new <div class="row"> every four elements, you just need one and add all next elements inside the <div class="col-md3">

Bootstrap will take care of the rest

Comment: Borjante when I did that there was a white space in between the elements. I may have done something wrong too. Thank you for your recommendation. I will try test it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($i%4==0)
{
    //close the existing div and start new row div here
}
```

That will start a new row after every 4 iterations

Comment: Thanks hanky Panky :) I added following code and it worked.  <?php
               if($i%4==0)
{
    //close the existing div and start new row div here
 
 echo "</div>";
    }
}
              ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM selection"; 
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $result[] = $rows;
}

$array = array_chunk($result, 4);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $row){
         ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> <strong><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></strong></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $row['ContactInfo']; ?><br/>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://myurl.com/selections/<?php echo $row['file_url']; ?>" >
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                      
<?php 
    }
}
```

Comment: Numan I will test your solution and see if your solution works as well. Thank you for your time.